# Trying to get value in Json String

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to get values for given below Json object for a given Abbreviation for a particular `formName` and all `sduedates(dueDate)`, The below pros variable only give code under `AbbForms`. With use of following variables can get upto forms

```
var pros = JObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(p => p.Name == "Abbforms").Children.ToList();
```

Json:::

```
"Abbreviation": "AQ",
"AbbreviationName": "Name1",

"Abbforms": [
  {
    "formName": "A for Partner1",
    "dueDate": [
      {
        "sdueDate": "2021-03-15T00:00:00+00:00",
        "month": "12",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2021-02-16T00:00:00+00:00",
        "month": "11",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2021-01-15T00:00:00+00:00",
         "month": "10",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-12-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "9",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-11-16T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "8",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "7",

      }
     {
        "sdueDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "6",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-08-17T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "5",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-07-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "4",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-06-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "3",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-05-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "2",

      },
      {
        "sdueDate": "2020-04-15T00:00:00+00:00",

        "month": "1",

      }
    ]
```

Comment: This is a classic example of taking the short road only to find it was actually the long road. Just Deserialize it and make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could create classes to represent the data and deserialize it. Then you can use `LINQ` to query the data.

These classes would represent the JSON. Note - the property names match the fields in your JSON:

```
class Data
{
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string AbbreviationName { get; set; }

    public List<Form> AbbForms { get; set; }
}

class Form
{
    public string FormName { get; set; }

    public List<Date> dueDate { get; set; }
}

class Date
{
    public DateTime sdueDate { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have loaded the json as a string you can then deserialize it:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Now you can use LINQ to query the data and get back the form you want:

```
var forms = data.AbbForms.Where(f => f.FormName == "A for Partner1");
```

You can do further research on [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq) to find out how to query the specific data you are looking for. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck with that :-)